# classLoader.getResource doesn't work in jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = classLoader.getResource("com/x/y/z.cfg");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

This works when running jar file from Eclipse but not works when running in a jar file.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\nova\Desktop\Matcher.jar!\c
>   om\x\y\z.cfg

**This is not a duplicate.** I've checked all other questions, no useful information.

Comment: What do you want to do with that `File` once you've got it?  You can't create a `File` from the `URL` you get for a resource in a JAR (because it's not a `file:` URL, it's typically `jar:file:/path/to/file.jar!/com/x/y/z.cfg`), but if the API you're using can accept a `URL` or an `InputStream` instead of a `File` then you don't need to.

Comment: This is explained many times: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944610/how-do-i-access-a-config-file-inside-the-jar), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/java-reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256/how-do-i-read-a-resource-file-from-a-java-jar-file?rq=1). The reson is really because File represents a file system object and contents of jar are not accessible by file system (but Java can handle it in some way - as an InputStream).

Comment: URL.getFile() *does not* convert a URL into a valid file path.  It merely returns the path portion of the URL.  (In the days of Java 1.0, most URLs referred to physical files;  that is why the method is named getFile.)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When file is bundled inside the jar then it become byte stream instead of a normal File object.

Try

```
InputStream stram=getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(relativePath);
```

[More Tutorial...](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-getresourceasstream-in-static-method/)

Read similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284014/java-getresourceasstream-jar-inside-war) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797786/loading-resource-from-jar-or-file-system-with-getresourceasstream)

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a File instance, because the only file you have is the JAR. That's why getResource() returns URL. You can get stream by using URL.openStream() method to read contents.