# classLoader.getResource doesn't work with Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, classloader

I am having the same problem `in JBoss but not in GlassFish` as mentioned here in an earlier question.

[classLoader.getResource doesn't work in jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675048/classloader-getresource-doesnt-work-in-jar-file][1])

But my problem is that I can not use `getResourceAsStream()`. It returns a stream object and I need a URL object as returned by `getResource()`. I am using that URL in a quite huge product. If I use stream I have to make a very big change.

Is there any way to get a URL instead of a stream?

Comment: Are you using URL.getFile() like that question is using? URL.getFile() *does not* convert a URL into a valid file path. It merely returns the path portion of the URL. (In the days of Java 1.0, most URLs referred to physical files, whether on the same system or on another system; that is why the method is named getFile.)  Do not attempt to convert your URL to a file.

Comment: @VGR no i am not using URL.getFile() but i am passing the URL object to a parser function. getResource() works fine but it doesnt work with Jboss. There is an alternative function getResourceAsStream() which was a suggestion in the answer of previous question but in my case I need URL not stream.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  How can you tell that the resource URL doesn’t work?

Comment: classLoader.getResource(name) returns null.

Comment: Are you saying that passing the same name to `getResourceAsStream` does not return null?  That seems unlikely.  What is the value of `name`?

Comment: No I didnt test getResourceAsStream() but it was in the answer of the question which I mentioned as a reference in my question. 
Anyways I have found a solution. The problem seems to be with the classLoader(). If I get classLoader from ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResource(name); it returns null but if I use another ClassLoader Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(name); it works fine.